# structural induction of haskell

Tags: haskell, currying, syntactic-sugar, induction

Hello everyone  I want to ask if  the following a definition of structural induction or not

```
init xs = take ( length xs - 1) xs

init :: [ a ] -> [ a ]
init ( x :[]) = []
init ( x : z : xs ) = x : init ( z : xs )
```

also Can someone give me an example of structural induction in Haskell?

Comment: You have two implementations of `init`, one using `take` and one using structural induction.

Comment: Structural induction is more a proof technique than a programming technique. Maybe you mean structural recursion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define what `init` *does*, so you have something to compare the implementation `take (length xs - 1) xs` against. Such a specification might be

```
 init [x] = []
 init (x:xs) = x : init xs
```

(The fact that this is basically a valid Haskell definition itself is one of the strengths of Haskell.)

To prove that `init xs = take (length xs - 1) xs` is correct, you need to prove that the definition satisfies the specification, using equational reasoning.

The base cases (every singleton list) is simple:

```
init [x] == take (length [x] - 1) [x]  -- definition of init
         == take (1 - 1) [x]  -- definition of length
         == take 0 [x]  -- arithmetic
         == []  -- using the definition of take
```

Having proven that `init` is correct for lists of length 1, the inductive hypothesis is that `init xs` is correct for any list `xs` of length `k > 1`. The inductive *step* is to prove that `init` is correct for a list `(x:xs)` of length `k + 1` (i.e., any list created by adding one more element to a list of length `k`).

```
init (x:xs) == take (length (x:xs) - 1) (x:xs)  -- definition of init
            == take (1 + length xs - 1) (x:xs)  -- definition of length
            == take (length xs) (x:xs)  -- arithmetic
            == x : take (length xs - 1) xs -- definition of take
            == x : init xs -- definition of init
```